# SPFieldUserValue User is null

Tags: development, sharepoint-addin, spuser

I have a list in which I can also view the version of each item.
Suppose I have an item ItemX which has been modified by UserX, I then delete UserX and try to view the version item of ItemX which had been modified by UserX.

When I want to retrieve the information about ModifiedBy, the returned string value is null and I found it is because of this:

```
SPFieldUserValue userValue =
                        (SPFieldUserValue)userField.GetFieldValue(fieldValue.ToString());
SPUser user = userValue.User;//null
```

I thought of creating an SPUser, but found that there is no constructor available for that. Any ideas on how I can get around that problem? Thanks!

Comment: UserX is deleted form AD or from SharePoint only? How/where?

Comment: Deleted from SharePoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [EnsureUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.ensureuser.aspx) method

```
SPUser user = web.EnsureUser(userValue.LoginName);
```

Comment: I still have a question. I checked in MSDN, what does this "Checks whether the specified logon name belongs to a valid user of the website, and if the logon name does not already exist, adds it to the website." mean? If I removed the user from the website, why is it adding it again??

Comment: It must add it back in order to get it as SPUser. AFAIK the user shouldn't have any permission on the site just by adding him with EnsureUser. For what do you need SPUser? Maybe another property of [SPFieldUserValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfielduservalue_members.aspx) is what you need?

Comment: I have a list which has Modified By and Created By fields. I want to retrieve the values for these two fields, but when the user has been deleted from the site collection, then I was not able to get these values using the code above.

Comment: Yes, but what you do with SPUser after you get it? If you must have it as SPUser then I don't know other way then EnsureUser, which will add the user back to the site. That shouldn't be a problem since the user will not get any rights on the site with EnsureUser alone (not tested).

Comment: I still don't understand why the User would be null. It is deleted from the User Information List, but from what I can see, it still exists in the UserInfo table